# How to make an image go under a <div> in HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So before actually creating my website, I first designed a wireframe for my website on [Balasmiq](https://balsamiq.com/wireframes/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7OLs4eOh8AIVfWpvBB19iQEtEAAYAyAAEgK38vD_BwE), which you can view from [here](https://balsamiq.cloud/s3npu49/psui38b/r2278). Now if you go into the wireframe, you will see the first section looking like this:
[image]

So I want the image of the phone under the first section, which is presumably going to be a `<div>`. Now in my code, I have used Bootstrap to create a navbar, and used the `col-lg-6` class to make my phone appear on the right:

[image]

But I want the image of the phone a little under the blue section of the screen(like in the wireframe), whereas in my code, it is in the entire screen. Ignore the h1 on the left of the screen. I have attached the code I have used with a running snippet, but the image doesn't load so download it from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+12+transparent+background+image&rlz=1C1UEAD_enCA932CA932&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii1NOi46HwAhVSds0KHSH8BbcQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=695#imgrc=BFcNvri0dlLGDM)

```css
.phone {
    height: 500px;
    width: 550px;
}
#title {
    background-color: #2978b5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Techno-Log</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Techno-Log</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Reviews</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Brands</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>Get the best technology updates and product news.</h1>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="phone" src="https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f8ebc300be77fed7b88aaf4/960x0.jpg?fit=scale" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: Please check my solution when you have a chance. It does exactly this with only one extra line of CSS. For a more complicated setup, you may need to use `position: absolute` but your example was very simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the concept clearly. It is a simple solution but hidden in plain sight. Thanks a lot, once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, to prevent the phone image from getting distorted, just use `height: auto`, and then to create that bleed effect, you should be able to just add a negative `margin-bottom` value, like this:

```css
.phone {
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -300px;
}
#title {
    background-color: #2978b5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Techno-Log</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Techno-Log</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Reviews</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Brands</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>Get the best technology updates and product news.</h1>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="phone" src="https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5f8ebc300be77fed7b88aaf4/960x0.jpg?fit=scale" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Brandon McConnell . I appreciate your help.

Comment: @GenisBillionaire no problem!